# How can I use TestScheduler with RxNetty http server

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-netty

I'm trying to create a simulation server to help make it easier to write tests for a client that operates on an event stream.

I'm implementing the server and client with RxNetty, my question is around how I can use a TestScheduler with RxNetty to control when events are emitted.

Here is my (simplified) server:

```
    final Observable<Event> events = Observable.just(...);
    final TestScheduler testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
    final HttpServer<ByteBuf, ByteBuf> server = RxNetty.createHttpServer(0, (request, response) -> {

        // [snip] validate request...

        return request.getContent().flatMap(buf ->
            events
                .zipWith(Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, testScheduler), (e, t) -> e)
                .map(Encoder::eventToBytes)
                .flatMap(response::writeBytesAndFlush)
        );
    });
    server.start();
```

However when I specify that `interval` should use `testScheduler` the server never sends any events. If I remove `testScheduler` or either `Schedulers.computation()` or `Schedulers.io()` the server is able to send events.

Here is the client/usage side that is expecting to receive the events coming from the server:

```
    final int serverPort = server.getServerPort();
    final URI uri = URI.create(String.format("http://localhost:%d/api/v1/scheduler", serverPort));
    final HttpClient<ByteBuf, ByteBuf> client = RxNetty.<ByteBuf, ByteBuf>newHttpClientBuilder(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort())
        .pipelineConfigurator(new HttpClientPipelineConfigurator<>())
        .build();

    final Event event = new Event("some event")

    final TestScheduler clientReceiveScheduler = new TestScheduler();
    final HttpClientRequest<ByteBuf> request = HttpClientRequest.createPost(uri.getPath())
        .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-protobuf")
        .withHeader("Accept", "application/x-protobuf")
        .withContent(event.toByteArray());

    final Observable<byte[]> observable = client.submit(request)
        .flatMap(AbstractHttpContentHolder::getContent)
        .map(BufUtils::bufToBytes)
        .zipWith(Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, clientReceiveScheduler), (b, l) -> b)
        .doOnNext((b) -> LOGGER.info("Received bytes: {}", Arrays.toString(b)));

    final TestSubscriber<Event> sub = new TestSubscriber<>();
    observable.subscribe(sub);

    testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    clientReceiveScheduler.advanceTimeBy(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    sub.getOnNextEvents()
        .stream()
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Here is a link to my [full server](https://github.com/BenWhitehead/mesos-rxjava/blob/scheduler-simulation/mesos-rxjava-test/src/main/java/com/mesosphere/mesos/rx/java/test/simulation/MesosSchedulerSimulation.java#L242) and a [test case](https://github.com/BenWhitehead/mesos-rxjava/blob/scheduler-simulation/mesos-rxjava-test/src/test/java/com/mesosphere/mesos/rx/java/test/simulation/MesosSchedulerSimulationStreamTest.java#L78) trying to use the server.

Answer (score 0):

`TestScheduler` requires you to advance time using its `advanceTime*` methods to trigger any scheduled actions. `Observable.interval()` schedules an action on the provided scheduler, which in this case is a `TestScheduler`. Without advancing time in the `TestScheduler`, it will never execute the actions; a tick of `Observable.interval()` in this case.

Removing RxNetty, if you look at this code:

```
    TestScheduler scheduler = Schedulers.test();
    TestSubscriber<Long> subscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();
    Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, scheduler)
              .take(1)
              .subscribe(subscriber);

    scheduler.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    System.out.println(subscriber.getOnNextEvents().size());
```

The output will always be 1. OTOH, if you comment out `scheduler.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);` it will always be 0.

Comment: Thanks @user2607715 I have been able to get the interval stuff to work with the test scheduler in a similar manner you describe here, I've even gotten it to work with RxNetty for receiving an event stream. However, I've not been able to get it to work with a server sending messages. I'll update my question to show what I'm doing on the client side of things.

Comment: @BenWhitehead the problem with the code is that there is an inherent race condition between a request received by the server and the `testScheduler` time being advanced.

In order to prove this hypothesis, if you add a sleep before advancing the test scheduler, you would see that you get the response as expected.

Comment: Thanks @Nitesh Kant I'll look into what I can do to work around that. I had incorrectly guessed that the servers threads wouldn't be impacted by the testScheduler.